# send mail in asp.net Bcc and CC

Tags: asp.net, email, send

i use code sendmail

```
public void sendmail()
{
    try
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");  
        EmailServerDAL emailDAL = new EmailServerDAL();
        EmailServer emailServer = emailDAL.FindByCondition(c => true).FirstOrDefault();
        string mail = emailServer.Email;
        string mailserver = emailServer.Mailserver;
        int port = int.Parse(emailServer.Mailport.ToString());
        string pass = emailServer.Pass;
        string detail = CKEditorControl1.Text;
        if (mailserver == "smtp.gmail.com")
        {
            MailMessage em = new MailMessage();
            em.IsBodyHtml = true;//khai báo body là html
            em.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;//khai báo body dùng mã UTF8
            //em.From = new MailAddress(CKEditorControl1.Text, "itool.vn");
            em.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtTo.Text, txtTitle.Text));
            //em.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtTo.Text, "ITOOL.VN"));
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtCC.Text))
            {
                em.CC.Add = TxtCC.Text.Replace(',', ';').Replace(" ", "");
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBCC.Text))
            {
                em.Bcc.Add = (new MailAddress(txtBCC.Text.Replace(',', ';').Replace(" ", "")));
            }
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string upload = Server.MapPath("~/upload/email/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(upload);
                Attachment attach = new Attachment(upload);
                em.Attachments.Add(attach);
            }
            em.Subject = txtTitle.Text;
            em.Body = detail;
            //em.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient();
            sm.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            sm.EnableSsl = true;
            sm.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mail, pass);
            sm.Send(em);
            lterror.Text = "<div class='Notice-Info'>Gởi mail thành công!</div>";
        }
```

}

I want send mail width Bcc and CC but error "Cannot assign to 'Add' because it is a 'method group'"

Answer (score 4):

The `Add` on a MailMessage is a method, not a property. So you don't assign the CC/BCC list to it, you pass it in as a parameter as you would with any other function.

```
em.CC.Add(TxtCC.Text.Replace(',', ';').Replace(" ", ""));

em.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(txtBCC.Text.Replace(',', ';').Replace(" ", "")));
```

Comment: How can I add Bcc and CC

Comment: @user2847541, Just as I showed you. What exactly are you having an issue with?